# Un nom pour l'action de compléter une action ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, noms

Existe-t-il un mot qui exprime l'action de compléter une action ? *Complétion* ? *Complitude* ? 
Y a-t-il un meilleur moyen d'exprimer cela ?

Comment: Dans quel contexte?

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu "compléter un action", plutôt finir ou achever une action, non? En fait, quand vous dites "compléter un action", je comprends "ajouter qq chose à une action pour l'améliorer".

Comment: Je confirme ce qu'écrit oli, *compléter* (fr) et *complete* (en) sont un peu des faux amis. Le champ sémantique est le même, mais pas les utilisations idiomatiques.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Je dirais *accomplissement* ou *achèvement* avec une préférence pour le premier.

Selon le CNRTL:

> [**Accomplissement**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/accomplissement):
>   Action d'accomplir. Résultat de cette action.
>
> [**Achèvement**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ach%C3%A8vement):
>   Action de mener à son terme; état de ce qui est arrivé à son terme.

Answer (score 13):

*[Complétion](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/compl%C3%A9tion/substantif)* et *[complétude](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/compl%C3%A9tude/substantif)* existent mais ne sont peut-être pas appropriés en dehors de certains cas spécifiques (philosophique, mathématique…).

Je préfère pour ma part *[clôture](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cl%C3%B4ture/substantif)* qui est souvent utilisé pour exprimer la fin d'opérations, et le simple *[fin](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fin/substantif)* peut suivant les cas convenir.

Answer (score 8):

Otiel a fourni deux exemples très intéressants. On peut aussi tout simplement utiliser le verbe terminer, ou mener/arriver à son terme. Si l'on souhaite un nom: le terme, la fin, l'aboutissement

> Le terme de ce travail.
>
> La fin des travaux
>
> L'aboutissement de la quête

Answer (score 2):

L'action de compléter ne suppose pas forcement celle de terminer.
Je propose : Enrichissement

Comment: Il peut y avoir des contextes où compléter quelque chose est un enrichissement, mais ce n'est pas vrai en général. Cette réponse pourrait être bonne si tu expliquais ses limitations.

Answer (score 0):

pourquoi tant de frilosité à utiliser complétion qui rend bien compte de la notion qui veut etre exprimée, qui existe dans la langue francaise, qui n'est pas vilain et qui est logique linguistiquement...? :-)

Comment: Parce que complétion ne veut pas dire achèvement en bon français. C'est un faux-ami du mot anglais.

Comment: @Kareen Selon le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/compl%C3%A9tion) : « Action de compléter; résultat de cette action, achèvement, accomplissement ». Ça ne convient pas dans tous les contextes, mais le sens existe.

Answer (score 0):

Si on pense à [*completion*](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/completion) et [*to complete*](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/complete), c'est essentiellement le passif de verbes qui exprime l'idée : [*être fini/achevé*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/completion/571505)*/terminé* ; on le voit [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1658/25619), ce peut être substantivé et reformulé dans un complémenent du nom. Ou comme dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1640/25619) où l'une des suggestions a pour synonyme quand il s'agit de l'action achevée : *achèvement, aboutissement, fin, terme, solution, but, destin, destinée, couronnement* ; mais ils ne traduisent pas *due for completion* ou  *near completion* comme le fait le verbe.

Answer (score 0):

Je suppose que je débarque fort en retard ... mais j'aimerais quand-même placer un mot sur ce qui a déjà été dit ici par tous mes prédécesseurs. À mon humble avis, *complétion* est l'*action* de compléter (rendre complet) ce qui est incomplet (un tableau, un formulaire, une information, une transaction, etc.) alors que *complétude* est l'*état* de ce qui est complet.

Donc, quand une chose *X* est incomplète, ce qu'on fait pour la compléter s'appelle la *complétion*, et le nouvel état de *X* est la *complétude*. La *complétion* est une *action* alors la *complétude* est un *état*. Aussi, la complétion assure la complétude.

Comment: On voit déjà ces deux suggestions et leurs définitions dans une autre réponse.  L'emploi des majuscules est-il nécessaire ? Voici le [tour] du site et bienvenue sur French Stack Exchange.

Comment: Italique ou gras sont normalement suffisant pour insister sur certains mots. Les majuscules nuisent à la lisibilité.

Answer (score 0):

Je dis « complètement » c'est ce qui est arrivé à terme.

Answer (score -1):

[Complétion](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/compl%C3%A9tion) :

> Action de compléter; résultat de cette action, achèvement, accomplissement

Comment: La description empruntée au TLFi mentionne une restriction de champ : *PHILOS. et lang. littér.*

Answer (score -1):

complètement
nom masculin
(de compléter)

Vieux. Action de mettre au complet : Le complètement d'une collection.

En topographie, report sur une minute obtenue par photogrammétrie des renseignements que la photographie aérienne ne peut fournir (toponymie, viabilité des routes, chemins sous bois, etc.).

Comment: Selon quelles sources ?

Comment: C'est pas interdit mais en général c'est pas très productif de répondre à une question d'il y a 5 ans qui a une réponse. Ça s'appelle un necropost et c'est utile pour pas grand monde.

Answer (score -1):

Je ne vois aucun des substantifs proposés valable dans le cas où l'on parle par exemple de compléter un tableau d'informations ou un formulaire. Et pourtant c'est dans ce cas qu'il est le plus usité. 
On ne parle pas de l'achèvement ou de l'accomplissement d'un formulaire, ni de son implémentation ou de son ajout : cela ne revêt alors plus du tout le même sens ! 
Le terme complétion renvoie plutôt à ce qui concerne le forage dun puits.
Dans le cas d'un formulaire, je ne vois que le mot "remplissage", même s'il n'est pas de la même origine étymologique.

Comment: Mais la question posée ne porte pas seulement sur le fait de remplir un formulaire, ou j'ai mal compris?Quand on fait du "remplissage", cela signifie qu'on comble des trous. Il me semble qu'il s'agit de compléter une action.

Answer (score -1):

Quand je finis de remplir un dossier administratif par exemple, je parle en général de la complétude de mon dossier, d'un formulaire, la complétion d'un profil LinkedIn... Les éléments existent déjà au départ, mais ne sont utiles qu'une fois complétés... D'où complétude ou complétion.
Je n'utiliserai ni enrichissement, ni aucun des autres termes ici employés.

Answer (score -1):

Complétion et achèvement sont les deux noms à l'extrème.                             Le premier ne signifie pas la fin de qch. mais y ajouter = l'enrichir, l'embellir, la gratifier etc d'autres indications importantes, comme une formation professionelle n'est jamais terminée, on pourra tj y ajouter une autre formation continue, donc la complèter > mais jamais totalement, comme elle ne connait pas de fin.                                                  Le deuxième est l'aboutissement total de qch, la mise à chef = tête = la partie suprême de tout > jusqu'à tuer q. > Il a été achevé.                                                                            ''Complétude'' est, comme déjà dit en haut, un état comme ''gratitude''

Comment: Comme ces exemples sont déjà donnés dans  les autres réponses, ça fait plutôt une commentaire.  Voici le [tour] du site et le [help].

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/20665)

Comment: En plus des remarques précédentes j'ajoute que l'utilisation de signes en tant que pseudo abréviations rend le tout incompréhensible.

Answer (score -2):

L'*implémentation*, un terme provenant de l'informatique semble relativement appropriée dans un contexte où l'on mettrait en place un dispositif permettant de réaliser une action initiale avec une légère variante par rapport à ce que permettait de réaliser la premiere.

Comment: Je ne vois pas le rapport avec la question. En plus, *implémentation*, personne ne connaît à part les programmeurs.

Comment: C'est utilisé dans d'autres domaines, comme la sociologie, l'architecture, même s'il est vrai que c'est très lié à l'informatique.

Answer (score -2):

Nom pour remplacer le verbe : "Compléter une action" = "Ajouter une action" -> Ajout complémentaire/supplémentaire

Comment: Comme l'indique la réponse acceptée, le sens recherché n'était pas celui-la.

Answer (score -3):

C'est le complément tout simplement ! Comme déménager -le déménagement

Comment: Que veut dire « TT »?

Comment: Difficile de trouver trace de cette définition au [dictionnaire](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/compl%C3%A9ment)... Et je serais très embêté avec qqch du genre *«Après cinquante ans de travaux, nous voyons enfin le complément de la construction de la cathédrale»*...